# How do I start my named instance of SqlServer.exe after killing it with taskmanager

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

How do I start all the sqlserver instances that normally come up when I reboot my computer?  I accidentally killed sql server instead of management studio.  This happened once before and I ended up rebooting my computer.

More specifically, how do I start my named instance?

let's say the named instance is .\MyNamedInstance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start..Run  services.msc

It's something like "SQL Server..." (Sorry, can't see right now)

Comment: after loading up the services window, I saw a list of available sql server instances.  The main instance was started up, but my named instance was still stopped.  After starting the instance, I was able to connect to it.

Answer (score 3):

```
 net start mssql$intancename
```